# Petition to reopen a CDC question

Tags: discussion

I am currently investigating whether to use the SQL Server feature *Change Data Capture* (CDC) for a data framework I am developing.

During my research I found much on *how* to use CDC, but not as much about *when* to use: In what kind of scenarios is CDC useful? (Point-in-time restoration of entries/audit/viewing change history) Where are its weaknesses compared to manual history tracking (e.g. trigger-based)?

So I came to dba in the hopes of finding an answer. Before I asked the question myself, I searched the existing questions and found this:

[Capture Data Change Vs Triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45098/capture-data-change-vs-triggers)

The question asks if CDC is useful in the given scenario. I would expect the answers to give an overview of when CDC is useful and when rather not to use it.

However, the question got closed for being too localized ("unlikely to help any future visitors") which is not true, because it likely would have helped me.

Is there any chance to reopen this question, maybe if we rephrased it to be a little bit more general? (What are valid usage scenarios/advantages of CDC?)

Should I rather open a new question? 
Or is the information I seek for not within the scope of this site?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. You can include the links to the related questions, (which do not really answer yours.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right thing to do here is definitely to ask your OWN question about your specific situation.

The existing question you linked to was very specific and was also a followup to a similar question from the same user (look at the comments on the question itself for a link).

If you have a question that's not answered, the right thing to do is ask it, as long as it fits into the scope of the site.

Comment: I followed your advice and opened a new question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/when-to-use-cdc-to-track-history